# Getting an error while following django tutorial

Tags: python, django

I am completely new to both django and python and currently I am following https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/ tutorial.

Getting the following error while running the command `python manage.py runserver`. Can anyone please help?

```
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x102cf8140>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/poojadeole/Desktop/venvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/poojadeole/Desktop/venvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/poojadeole/Desktop/venvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/poojadeole/Desktop/venvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/poojadeole/Desktop/venvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/poojadeole/Desktop/venvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Users/poojadeole/Desktop/venvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/Users/poojadeole/Desktop/venvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Users/poojadeole/Desktop/venvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/poojadeole/Desktop/venvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/poojadeole/Desktop/venvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/poojadeole/Desktop/venvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/poojadeole/Desktop/projectdjango/mysite/mysite/urls.py", line 16, in <module>
    from django.urls import include, path
ImportError: cannot import name include
```

Comment: Are you able to see manage.py in same directory?

Comment: Django2.0 do not support python2.7 anymore!!!

Comment: "This tutorial is written for Django 2.0, which supports Python 3.4 and later." You have using Python 2.7.

Comment: @KlausD.  maybe thats the reason. Will try updating it..thanks

Answer (score 3):

Actually **include** is present in `django.conf.urls`

In **urls.py** in place of `from django.urls import include` write below code

```
from django.conf.urls import include
```

Comment: For someone new who is following a tutorial, this answer not only is not useful, is actually confusing. Care to add more explanation, to make your post actually useful?

Comment: @Adelin, Now it should help.

Comment: And how shall i import the path? My mysite/urls.py  looks like this:                                                          from django.conf.urls import include,                  
from django.urls import path,                          
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

Comment: In django2.0 you can use both

Comment: `from django.urls import path` for path

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using python 2.7 and from fact that django 2.0 does not support python 2.7(see [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#python-compatibility)) I suppose you are working with older version of Django.

In this case you may find `include` function here `django.conf.urls`:

```
from django.conf.urls import include
```

Qoute from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#include):

> Changed in Django 2.0:
>   In older versions, this function is located in django.conf.urls. The old location still works for backwards compatibility.

So if you use Django 2.0 you can import include with both methods:

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.urls import include
```

But for previous version only first one is correct.

As for [path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#path), it is absolutely new in Django 2.0. In older version you should use [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/#url):

```
from django.conf.urls import url
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Python 2.x and Django 1.x but the tutorial is for Django 2.x so you need to update to Python 3 and use pip to download Django 2.1 the latest and it works fine. Possible causes could be the use of an IDE to download Django and Python as the plugin's in some of the IDE stick to outdated versions. Visual Studio and Intellij Idea plugins are the main cause. I would recommend VS Code with integrated command tool for Django.